MS Access Insert into Type Mismatch
I'm trying to insert 3 fields into a table, Tbl_BOM_Requirments.
from another table, tblSCSPartNumbering
Where the PrtNmber_LinkField = [SCS Part Number] and ID = [ID]
And I keep getting a type mismatch error... but i can't find why.
Private Sub RequiredMaterialPrtNum_AfterUpdate()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim MrTestical As String
Dim SCSprtNum As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim ScsId As String


MrTestical = Forms![RFQNewPartV2]![SCS Part Number]
SCSprtNum = Forms![RFQNewPartV2]![SCS Part Number]
ScsId = Me.ID

[PrtNmber_LinkField] = MrTestical

Set db = CurrentDb


 strSQL = "INSERT INTO Tbl_BOM_Requirments ([MstrBomPlySize],[MstrBomPlyQty],[ReqrdQty]) " & vbCrLf & _
"SELECT tblSCSPartNumbering.[PrtPlySizeMSTR],[PrtPlyCountMSTR],[PrtRqurdQtyMSTR]" & vbCrLf & _
"FROM tblSCSPartNumbering " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE (tbl_BOM_Requirments.PrtNmber_LinkField) = """ & SCSprtNum & "" And (tbl_BOM_Requirments.ID) = """ & ScsId & """""""
 db.Execute strSQL
     
End Sub

Any suggestions would be greatly apricated... I'm 5 hours deep into and starting to get a little bit hot under the collar

are you missing a quote after """ & SCSprtNum & ""

How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA

Just a tiny little side point...
When building SQL dynamically, including double-quotes gets annoying very quickly. Luckily, it is normally acceptable to simply use single quotes within the SQL and it will very often work. This makes it much easier to manage longer or more complicated SQL-building code.

Correct the quotes and use the source table name:
strsql = "INSERT INTO Tbl_BOM_Requirments ([MstrBomPlySize],[MstrBomPlyQty],[ReqrdQty]) " & vbCrLf & _
"SELECT tblSCSPartNumbering.[PrtPlySizeMSTR],[PrtPlyCountMSTR],[PrtRqurdQtyMSTR]" & vbCrLf & _
"FROM tblSCSPartNumbering " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE tblSCSPartNumbering.PrtNmber_LinkField = """ & SCSprtNum & """ And tblSCSPartNumbering.Id = """ & ScsID & """"

If Id is numeric:
strsql = "INSERT INTO Tbl_BOM_Requirments ([MstrBomPlySize],[MstrBomPlyQty],[ReqrdQty]) " & vbCrLf & _
"SELECT tblSCSPartNumbering.[PrtPlySizeMSTR],[PrtPlyCountMSTR],[PrtRqurdQtyMSTR]" & vbCrLf & _
"FROM tblSCSPartNumbering " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE tblSCSPartNumbering.PrtNmber_LinkField = """ & SCSprtNum & """ And tblSCSPartNumbering.Id = " & ScsID & ""

